# How can I position the last row of my query to appear below the result? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, union

I have a MySQL database query that retrieves ordered items from a **sales_order_table.** The script returns the **products** and their **quantity**. Below each quantity there appears the product id.

The **output** of my **current query** looks like this:
[image]

**Problem:** The row with a blue highlight that says **cost** must be positioned below all of the products ordered

The **Final Output** I want to achieve must look like this:
[image]

The code that I used is this:

```
SET @origin=0;

SELECT order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value, row, origin FROM (

SELECT bsb.ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_qty' AS meta_key, bsb.QUANTITY AS meta_value, @a:= @a + 1 AS row, @origin:= @origin +1 AS origin
FROM bsb,(SELECT @a:=0) t
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (300)
UNION

SELECT bsb.ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_product_id' AS meta_key, bsb.PRODUCT_ID AS meta_value,   @b:= @b + 1 AS row, @origin:= @origin +1 AS origin
FROM bsb, (SELECT @b:=0) t
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (300)
UNION       

SELECT '' AS meta_id, bso.ID AS order_item_id, 'cost' AS meta_key, 0 AS meta_value,  @j:= @j + 1 AS row, @origin:= @origin +1 AS origin
FROM bso, (SELECT @j:=1) t
WHERE bso.ID IN (300)

) sales_order_meta ORDER BY row, origin
```

Kindly Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ORDER BY` clause to:

```
ORDER BY order_item_id, meta_key = 'cost', row, origin
```

`meta_key = 'cost'` is `1` for the `cost` row, `0` for all other rows.

Comment: Hello Barmar, Thank you for your response. Your suggestion is working. But in my case, I have 3 more order_item_id's I want the cost row to appear just below all of the products ordered according to the order_item_id.. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Add the `order_item_id` into your `ORDER BY` clause so that will be the main grouping.

Comment: Your question says you want the `cost` line to be below **all** of the products ordered, not just below all the other rows for the same `order_item_id`.

Comment: There's probably no reason to bother setting `@row` and `@origin` in the `cost` subquery.